# setting attribute false on more login attempts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

this is the code i am using for generating recaptcha, if user signin fails.
In this i have to check other scenario where if user login_attempts exceeds 4, then we have to make the user status false.

Session_controller:

> def create
>
> ```
> cookies[:email] =   params[:user][:email]
>
> Rails.logger.debug("auth_options: #{auth_options.inspect}")      
>
> self.resource =  warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
>
> if cookies[:email]
>   cookies[:login_attempts] = 0
>   set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
>   sign_in(resource_name, resource)
>   if current_user.status != false
>     respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
>   else
>     destroy
>     flash[:error] = "Your account is locked"
>   end
>
> else
>   unless params[:user][:email].blank?
>     if   cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])
>       cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
>     else
>       cookies[:login_attempts] = 0
>     end
>
>   end
>   render :new
> end
> ```
>
> end

The below is the code i have to implement in above create method:

> if cookies[:login_attempts].to_i > 4
>
> ```
>         current_user.update_attribute(:status,false)
>
>         flash[:error]= "your account is dismissed"
>
>       end
> ```

could you please tell me where i have to include this? Tried to put in and around but bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
unless params[:user][:email].blank?
if   cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])
  cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
  if cookies[:login_attempts].to_i > 4
    current_user.update_attribute(:status,false)
    flash[:error]= "your account is dismissed"
  end
else
  cookies[:login_attempts] = 0
end
end
```

And I will suggest you to use sessions for this task cookies can be override.

Comment: I tried the above one its not working. And sorry to mention now, i am also involving failed_attempts in sessions_controller/ new method:     'def new  
    cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts] || 0  
    if params[:user] && cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])
      cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1  
    else  
      cookies[:login_attempts] = 0  
    end  
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)  
    clean_up_passwords(resource)  
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))  
  end '

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is not good way because cookie can desable, add  another columns `counts` into db respective table, then write increase count value into respective model such as

```
class User .....
  def self.counts
     self.update_attributes(counts: counts+1)
     self.counts
  end
end
```

Now in controller

```
if User.counts > 4
  current_user.update_attribute(:status,false)
  flash[:error]= "your account is dismissed"
end
```

and if user email valid then update count with 0

```
current_user.update_attributes(counts: 0)
```